# Flask-wtf error message is not appearing properly

Tags: flask, flask-wtforms

The error message of the form I am creating is not appearing with the bootstrap style I put.
Here is the form.py code:

```
class SearchForm(FlaskForm):
    search = StringField('Número do protocolo', validators=[DataRequired()])
    submit = SubmitField('Buscar')
```

Here is the .html code:

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% block sub_content %}
<br><br>
<form method="POST" action="">
    {{ form.hidden_tag() }}
    <fieldset class="form-group">
        <legend class="border-bottom mb-4">Veja o andamento da sua denúncia</legend>
        <div class="form-group">
            {{ form.search.label(class="form-control-label") }}
            
            {% if form.search.errors %}
                {{ form.search(class="form-control is-invalid") }}
                <div class="invalid-feedback">
                    {% for error in form.search.errors %}
                        <span>{{ error }}</span>
                    {% endfor %}
                </div>
            {% else %}
                {{ form.search(class="form-control") }}
            {% endif %}
            
            
        </div>
    </fieldset>
    <div class="form-group">
        {{ form.submit(class="btn btn-secondary") }}
        <a href="/client1/"><input type="button" value="Voltar" class="btn btn-secondary"></a>
    </div>
</form>
{% endblock %}
```

Even though the html code has the error style shown below:

```
{% if form.search.errors %}
                {{ form.search(class="form-control is-invalid") }}
                <div class="invalid-feedback">
                    {% for error in form.search.errors %}
                        <span>{{ error }}</span>
                    {% endfor %}
                </div>
            {% else %}
```

It keeps showing the random error message in the image below:

[error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bpspw.jpg)

Comment: The Flask-WTF errors only get created when your form has been sent to the server and the fields validated against the list of `validators`. But you'll also find if you inspect the rendered HTML, the `DataRequried()` validator has rendered your `search` field with a `required` attribute, which the causes the browser to pop up with that warning before it even gets sent.

Answer (score 2):

The solution is really simple, you only need to add a 'novalidate' Tag to the Form. There is nothing wrong with your code.

This is because the browser is responding before the flask form can even be validate it and no 'errors' are actualli rendered.

Therefore the HTML form would look like this:

```
 <!-- Note the 'validate' tag -->
    <form method="POST" action="" novalidate>
            {{ form.hidden_tag() }}
            <fieldset class="form-group">
                <legend class="border-bottom mb-4">Veja o andamento da sua denúncia</legend>
                <div class="form-group">
                    {{ form.search.label(class="form-control-label") }}
                    
                    {% if form.search.errors %}
                        {{ form.search(class="form-control is-invalid") }}
                        <div class="invalid-feedback">
                            {% for error in form.search.errors %}
                                <span>{{ error }}</span>
                            {% endfor %}
                        </div>
                    {% else %}
                        {{ form.search(class="form-control") }}
                    {% endif %}
                    
                    
                </div>
            </fieldset>
            <div class="form-group">
                {{ form.submit(class="btn btn-secondary") }}
                <a href="/client1/"><input type="button" value="Voltar" class="btn btn-secondary"></a>
            </div>
        </form>
```

### REFERENCES

> **novalidate** Tag ----> [w3school](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_form_novalidate.asp)

> **Guide**  -----> [Miguel Grinberg](https://blog.miguelgrinberg.com/post/the-flask-mega-tutorial-part-iii-web-forms)